# Set system to shutdown, if inccorrect login credentials entered

Tags: login, password, security, encryption, shutdown

Many threads exist on the web, with people wanting an auto-destruct feature, if an incorrect password is entered when unlocking their disk. What I want, however, is simply for the system to shut-down, if invalid login credentials are repeatedly entered, at the user-login screen, or the lock-screen. I have full disk encryption, so if the computer shuts-down, my data would be much safer. I am mainly concerned about somebody trying to snoop around on my computer, while I am out of my hotel room. I typically turn the thing off if I am going to leave for an extended period of time, but if I am gone for less than an hour or so, or if I have a large file downloading, it would be nice to simply lock the screen/put it to sleep.

Any ideas?

Comment: If your goal was achieved and the system automatically shut down after 3 invalid sign on attempts, the spy could simply push the power button to get the sign on screen back again. Perhaps I'm missing something here?

Comment: Since I have full-disk encryption, in order to return to the login screen, one would first have to unlock the disk.  That is,  the system will not boot, until the correct pass-phrase is entered.  Only then, is the user-login screen displayed.

Comment: Now I see your point. If they fail the second login, they get downgraded back to the first login which they would repeatedly get when they rebooted.

Comment: Correct. It seems more feasible, and, in my case, more desirable, than trying to make the system self-destruct, as some have suggested on the net. Brute-forcing my disk pass-phrase is unrealistic, with such a small window of opportunity. There are many hypothetical scenarios that may get tossed out here, but this feature would provide me with what I feel is a reasonable measure of additional security, and is something I think others might be interested in as well.